# Apache .htaccess rewrite condition not working on remoter server. only works on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the following htaccess rules:

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule news/press_releases/([1-9][0-9]*)/([1-9][0-9]*)/(.*).html$ /news/news-details.php?newsYear=$1&newsMonth=$2&newsID=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule news/archive-([1-9][0-9]*).php$ /news/archive.php?arhYear=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule rss.xml$ /rss.php
```

It works on my localhost and I used the same code for remote server. 
In that remote server, the second rewrite condition and rules doesn't working.

The following part not working on my remote server:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule news/archive-([1-9][0-9]*).php$ /news/archive.php?arhYear=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: And "not working" means what _exactly_? Do you get an error? A wrong rewriting? Does nothing happen? Does the universe implode?

Comment: Is the code on remote server in the same folder (relative to document root) as on localhost? Perhaps try adding a RewriteBase?

Comment: For us to know whether it should work or not we need to know what URLs you are requesting that you expect to match. Btw, a `RewriteBase` directive would be superfluous here since you have no relative path substitutions.